# How can I create an .hpp for namespaces containing template classes?

Tags: c++, templates, header

I have to use C++ for a project (normally doing Haskell and C)
and I completely hang on headers for namespaces.
When I leave away the "arrays.hpp" and directly include
"arrays.cpp" into other files (which is bad practice, I know).
The code works fine, but when I try to define the header for the following code it no longer works (of course, I still pass all the .cpps to g++).
I already read several Stack Overflow posts on that topic,
but none of the proposed solutions worked for me,
so I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how the header for this code might look.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "arrays.hpp"

namespace Arrays {
  template<typename Field> class Array {
    private:
    int rank;
    int* shape;
    Field* data;
    public:
    Array(int _rank, int* _shape, Field* _data) {
      rank = _rank;
      shape = _shape;
      data = _data;
    }
    Array(std::vector<Field> vector) {
      rank = 1;
      shape = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
      shape[0] = (int)vector.size();
      data = (Field*)malloc(sizeof(Field)*vector.size());
      for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
        data[i] = vector[i];
    }
  };
}
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
#ifndef ARRAYS_HPP

#define ARRAYS_HPP

namespace Arrays {
  template<typename Field> class Array;
}

#endif
```

And this is G++'s response after invoking it with `g++ *.cpp`):

```
error: variable ‘Arrays::Array<int> array’ has initializer but incomplete type
```

Comment: Why are you rolling that on your own if I'm allowed to ask?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with `rolling that on your own`.

Comment: @einmensch The `Array` stuff I meant.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Nope, not in this case.

Comment: Yes I have to. I develop math software and in this case I am going to write a library with Array algorithms.

Comment: @einmensch Use `std::vector`, `std::array`, and other standard library containers. There is no reason to be creating this stuff yourself.

Comment: std::array and std::vector are completely non-related things. They both define lists, but I define Arrays aka Hyper Matrices

Comment: @cdhowie I guess you are not that familiar with the mathematical background, but its not even part of the question, so why comment that ?

Comment: There's no reason you can't use the existing containers to implement the higher level mathematical concepts you need.  Managing your own memory is completely unnecessary in this context. Write new classes, but compose them from standard containers when possible.